# Show many google charts in one chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have many google charts, I have google chart for each week

For example .
i have data

for week 2017/5/1 to 2017/5/8

`[[date,'real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/1',0,35]['2017/5/2',3,34],['2017/5/3',7,36],['2017/5/4',10,38]['2017/5/5',16,36],['2017/5/6',31,40]['2017/5/7',35,40]['2017/5/8',40,40]]`

Then i have graph for week 2017/5/8 to 2017/5/15
  `[[date,'real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_weektotal_likes'],['2017/5/8',0,42],['2017/5/9',3,39],['2017/5/10',10,40],['2017/5/11',16,41],['2017/5/12',20,40],['2017/5/13',31,43],['2017/5/14',35,41],['2017/5/15',43,43]]`

I can show them separately on one page like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawweek1);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values

function drawweek1() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
 [['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/1',0,35],['2017/5/2',3,34],['2017/5/3',7,36],['2017/5/4',10,38],['2017/5/5',16,36],['2017/5/6',31,40],['2017/5/7',35,40],['2017/5/8',40,40]]  
);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'week1', 'width':550, 'height':400,'pointSize': 10,'hAxis':{
        'slantedText': true, 
          'slantedTextAngle':30},'vAxis':{}};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="differnt"
 $elem = document.getElementById('chart_week1');
   if($elem === null){return;}
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_week1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
} 
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawweek2);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values

function drawweek2() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
 [['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/8',0,42],['2017/5/9',3,39],['2017/5/10',10,40],['2017/5/11',16,41],['2017/5/12',20,40],['2017/5/13',31,43],['2017/5/14',35,41],['2017/5/15',43,43]]  
);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'week2', 'width':550, 'height':400,'pointSize': 10,'hAxis':{
        'slantedText': true, 
          'slantedTextAngle':30},'vAxis':{}};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="differnt"
 $elem = document.getElementById('chart_week2');
   if($elem === null){return;}
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_week2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  
} 


</script>

<div id="chart_week1"></div>
<div id="chart_week2"></div>
```

I have many graphs like this. is there any way i can show them on the one graph it should still show the data of one week , But user should able to change to previous week or next week,

The main problem here is at the end of every week one date has two sets of values. For example at 2017/5/8 we  have ['2017/5/8',40,40] and ['2017/5/8',0,42]. other wise i could combine all the data into one array. And use the method of DATAVIEW as explained here [Show only seven days of data on google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037457/show-only-seven-days-of-data-on-google-chart) By WhiteHat.

Comment: @WhiteHat WhiteHat, I meant 2017/5/8', We have two sets of values.. `['2017/5/8',40,40] and ['2017/5/8',0,40]`, So it would be array like this `[[date,'real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/1',0,35]......['2017/5/7',35,40],['2017/5/8',40,40],['2017/5/8',0,40],['2017/5/9',x,x].....]`

Comment: No day missing . Same pattern daily @WhiteHat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the other answer, `getFilteredRows` is used to find the row indexes to be displayed on the chart...

```
// filter date range
view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 0,
  minValue: new Date(2017, 6, 8),
  maxValue: new Date(2017, 6, 15)
}]));
```

instead, manually specify the row indexes...

```
view.setRows([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],
      ['2017/5/2',3,34],
      ['2017/5/3',7,36],
      ['2017/5/4',10,38],
      ['2017/5/5',16,36],
      ['2017/5/6',31,40],
      ['2017/5/7',35,40],
      ['2017/5/8',40,40],
      ['2017/5/8',0,40],  // <-- repeat
      ['2017/5/9',3,39],
      ['2017/5/10',10,40],
      ['2017/5/11',16,41],
      ['2017/5/12',20,40],
      ['2017/5/13',31,43],
      ['2017/5/14',35,41],
      ['2017/5/15',41,41]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    // convert first column to date
    view.setColumns([{
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'date'
    }, 1, 2]);

    var current_week = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    var next_week = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

    // filter date range
    view.setRows(current_week);

    $('#next_week').on('click', function () {
      view.setRows(next_week);
      drawChart();
    });

    drawChart();
    function drawChart() {
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
      chart.draw(view);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="next_week" value="next week" />
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I think you did what i wanted, But i need more time to understand this. I am gonna try this myself. and  I saw your previous answers on google-charts", I must say, "you nailed it". Thanks :)

Comment: Works great man ! I just add ['2017/5/1',0,35] in the dataArray (of your code), And change ` var current_week = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7];
    var next_week = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,14,15];` , And get what i wanted. Can't thank you enough :) :)

Answer (score 0):

WhiteHat gave a great answer. But i found one more way to do this. I don't know better or worse but might useful for someone

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawweek1);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values

function drawweek1() {
 var total_weeks = 3;
 
 var data1 =google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/15',0,33],['2017/5/16',3,40],['2017/5/17',10,47],['2017/5/18',16,42],['2017/5/19',20,41],['2017/5/21',31,43],['2017/5/22',35,41],['2017/5/23',43,43]]);  
 
var data2 =google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/8',0,42],['2017/5/9',3,39],['2017/5/10',10,40],['2017/5/11',16,41],['2017/5/12',20,40],['2017/5/13',31,43],['2017/5/14',35,41],['2017/5/15',43,43]]);  


 var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
 [['date','real_likes_this_week_till_now','expected_this_week_total_likes'],['2017/5/1',0,35],['2017/5/2',3,34],['2017/5/3',7,36],['2017/5/4',10,38],['2017/5/5',16,36],['2017/5/6',31,40],['2017/5/7',35,40],['2017/5/8',40,40]]  
);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'weeks', 'width':550, 'height':400,'pointSize': 10,'hAxis':{
        'slantedText': true, 
          'slantedTextAngle':30},'vAxis':{}};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="differnt"
 $elem = document.getElementById('chart_week1');
   if($elem === null){return;}
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_week1'));
   $('#next_graph').hide();
    if(total_weeks == 1){$('#previous_graph').hide();}
    chart.draw(data1, options);
  $('#previous_graph').on("click",function(){
  var current_graph =   $('#which_graph').val();  
  var previous_graph = parseInt(current_graph) + 1 ;
  if(previous_graph == total_weeks){$(this).hide();}
   $('#next_graph').show();
   $('#which_graph').val(previous_graph);
    var previous_data = "data" + previous_graph;
      new_data = eval(previous_data);
      chart.draw(new_data, options);
  });
  $('#next_graph').on("click",function(){
  var current_graph =   $('#which_graph').val(); 
  var next_graph = parseInt(current_graph) - 1 ;
   if(next_graph ==1){$(this).hide();}
   $('#previous_graph').show();
   $('#which_graph').val(next_graph);
    var next_data = "data" + next_graph;
      new_data = eval(next_data);
      chart.draw(new_data, options);
  });
  
} 

</script>

<div id="chart_week1"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="which_graph" value =1>
<button id="previous_graph">Previous</button>
<button id="next_graph">Next </button>
```